# Instagram or Facebook as Service Provider

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, instagram, openid-connect

My client wants to use Instagram or Facebook as Service Provider. We can use SAML or OIDC/OAuth for it. Our IDP is OneLogin which supports both protocol.

Is there any way we can configure Instagram or Facebook as Service Provider?

Answer (score 1):

OneLogin has apps available in the app catalog that are preconfigured for Facebook and Instagram. For specific steps on how to configure these apps you should have the OneLogin customer open a support ticket through their support portal.

Comment: thank you for the comment. As mentioned in question, I want their them to OIDC SP. All OneLogin has is either Form Based or SAML which is not use to me